# Stepts to take when converting cookie session to active_record_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

We have a live system and I want to convert our cookie session to active_record_store.

I have deployed the changes and a few users had issues logging in (unless they cleared cookies) and a user who couldn't log in at all.

What are the steps that I need to take in order to cleanly migrate our session store?

Comment: Did you try changing the `secret_key_base`?

Comment: That was what was suggested but I don't think active_record_store uses that since changing secret_key_base had no effect. I think the cookie stored is the id of the session in the db (without encryption)

Comment: Interesting...so if you login, change the key, restart server, then refresh, you're still logged in?

Comment: Yeah that was the confusing part trying to resolve this. I use heroku and I deploy the changes and restarted all dynos, I was still logged in

Comment: In a pinch I might just add a secret to the session and if it's not there, destroy session and redirect to sign-in page. But I'm with you, it shouldn't be so hard! I'll keep an eye on this thread!